# Would [field-technique] be a useful tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[A comment](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/when-can-taste-be-used-to-help-identify-rocks#comment-1981) by [plannapus](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/87/plannapus) suggested that [field-technique](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-technique) might be a useful tag for the question. (I had thought of "field-methods", but "field-technique" has a more technical feel.)

Would [field-technique](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-technique) be a useful tag and is that the best name for the category?

Comment: +1 Clearly, all my opinion, but [tag:field-work] might be a more general tag, and as a result, be more useful. [tag:rock-identification] appears to merit its own tag, and it is unlikely in my opinion that someone looking to find or tag a question related to rock identification would look for field related tags.

Comment: @blunders Why not make that an answer, allowing people to downvote if they disagree. This is Meta, so receiving downvotes is not nearly as painful (and giving them has no reputation cost even for answers).

Answer (score 6):

[field-work](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-work) might be a more general tag than either "field-methods", but "field-technique" - and as a result, may be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

[rock-identification](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rock-identification) appears to merit its own tag, and it is unlikely in my opinion that someone looking to find or tag a question related to rock identification would look for field related tags.